# Java-How to make delay/wait in the particular block

Tags: java, swing

I want Something like when user hits the login button loading process should go on displayed.after few seconds the message box with Message should be displayed and the loading process should be hidden.
but my problem in my code is both the loading process and message is displayed at same time after the delay.
here is my code

```
b.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String path="C:\\Users\\xxxxx\\yyyyyy\\Load.gif";
            loading.setIcon(new ImageIcon(path));
            loading.setBounds(400, 200, 350, 300);

            if(user_name.equals(str) && pass.equalsIgnoreCase(str)){

                    try {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Login Success");
                     loading.setVisible(false);
                  TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);

                  } catch (InterruptedException e1) {

                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Comment: Consider using a SwingWorker, which would allow you to perform the login in in the background and either use a PropertyChangeListener or override the done method to display the message

Answer (score 2):

There's a couple of ways you might do this, one of the simpler and safer is to use a `SwingWorker`, see [Worker Threads and SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) for more details

```
public class LoginWorker extends SwingWorker<Boolean, Void> {

    private String userName;
    private char[] password;

    public LoginWorker(String userName, char[] password) {
        this.userName = userName;
        this.password = password;
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground() throws Exception {
        // Here is where you do the actualy login process...
        // You'll notice I passed the login/password to the constructor
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        return true;
    }

}
```

And make use of it...

```
btnLogin.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        btnLogin.setEnabled(false);
        LoginWorker worker = new LoginWorker("username", new char[]{'p', 'a', 's', 's', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'd'});
        worker.addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
                SwingWorker<Boolean, Void> worker = (SwingWorker<Boolean, Void>) evt.getSource();
                if ("state".equals(evt.getPropertyName())) {
                    SwingWorker.StateValue state = (SwingWorker.StateValue) evt.getNewValue();
                    switch (state) {
                        case DONE: {
                            btnLogin.setEnabled(true);
                            try {
                                boolean result = worker.get();
                                if (result) {
                                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(TestPane.this, "Login was successful");
                                } else {
                                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(TestPane.this, "Login was unsuccessful");
                                }
                            } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException ex) {
                                ex.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        worker.execute();
    }
});
```

I've chosen to make use of the `PropertyChangeListener` in this case, as it decouples the process, but you could extend the `LoginWorker` and override it's `done` method instead, but then you'd need some kind of observer pattern anyway